# Reset master branch to feature branch

Tags: git, rebase

We have a `master` branch and feature branch called `feature/google-analytics`.
The feature branch was created from the `master` branch. 
There are so many hotfixes applied in the `master` branch.

But now when I try to rebase with master branch, it shows many conflicts. so I aborted the git rebase.
Instead, apply the hotfixes manually to the feature branch.

Now I want to reset master branch same as feature branch.
How to do that?

Comment: Why not merge `master` into the feature branch, and then vice-versa?  A merge would just land you once with a bunch of conflicts, which is simpler than a rebase.  Resetting `master` to the feature branch doesn't feel quite right to me.

Comment: Don't be scared of conflicts!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT - How to make a branch be the same as master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796127/git-how-to-make-a-branch-be-the-same-as-master)

Answer (score 1):

In order to reset a branch to another remote branch, you can simply use

```
git reset --hard origin/feature/google-analytics
```