# 2 git branches should be the same after merge, but are not

Tags: git, github

I'm not sure how to explain this appropriately in the title, so here's the situation. I have 2 branches, master and staging. Recently, I pulled staging into master to get production up to date. There were a *ton* of conflicts. I went with this and resolved them because it had been a while since a push to production. However, that was just 2 days ago. I've since made 2 smallish commits to staging and would like to pull staging into master again, however, I'm getting a *ton* of merge conflicts again, things that happened several months ago. Should these branches not be up to date with each other since I had just recently merged them?

I've looked into it a bit and I'm not finding any information to be honest. My goal is to make master the exact same as staging. Is `git reset --hard` an option? I'm not sure if this made any sense to do, but I tried first merging master into staging and resolving those conflicts and then staging into master, but that didn't result in anything.

Solution:

I'm not realy sure... Somehow these branches haven't actually been merged for the last two months, which is what's causing such a massive PR again. The perplexing part is that when I did merge them two days ago, everything went through fine and production had the latest changes. Anyways, I went ahead and merged them once more, hoping that takes. I will create a few commits at some point and try again, hopefully it won't be a massive PR again. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: How did you resolve the conflicts? If you did anything but accept the changes from staging then no: they wouldn't have the same history.

Comment: That's all I did! I accepted all the changes from staging. Basically, master needs to be the same as staging, if there was a way to overwrite it would be fine as well.

Comment: @Ranga They wouldn't have the same history anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT - How to make a branch be the same as master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796127/git-how-to-make-a-branch-be-the-same-as-master)

Comment: @Joe That might, though it seems that he has the reverse issue. I'd like to reset master with staging. Master doesn't matter to me at all, other than it's hooked to production. I want master to be the exact same as staging, would this work?

`git checkout master`
`git reset --hard staging`
`git push -f`
?

Comment: Yep, but you lose commits that were only in master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make master look exactly like staging (in terms of content) with a revisión that looks like a merge you should look a little outside from the normal tools:

```
git commit-tree -p master -p staging -m "make master just like staging" staging^{tree}
```

That will create a revision just like the one you are asking for and will print the ID on the output. Check it with whatever tool you feel like. If you like how it looks, then move master to it:

```
git branch -f master <the-id>
git checkout master
```

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like exactly what I want to do. My only concern is that if I do this and then pull in branch `new-feature` to staging for testing and then merge that into master again, will I end up with all the issues all over? Seems like I wouldn't, but just want to check. I'll look into that commit-tree command

Comment: Also what is the {tree} in the first line, is that a placeholder for something?

Comment: *<commit-ish>^{tree}* means get the tree of the specified commit.

Comment: git will take care of resolving `staging^{tree}`. Just write it on the command line (assuming the name of the branch is `staging`).

Comment: But as @krisz said, it's just writing the tree ID of the revision that staging branch is pointing to.

Comment: Okay perfect, Thanks @krisz and @eftshift0!

Answer (score 1):

This does the same as [eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0)'s answer without plumbing commands:

```
git switch master
git merge stage --no-commit
git restore --worktree --staged --source stage :/
git commit
```

If you want to avoid merge conflicts in the future, you can adopt the following workflow (from [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project)):

> If you have a more important project, you might want to use a
>   two-phase merge cycle. In this scenario, you have two long-running
>   branches, master and develop, in which you determine that master is
>   updated only when a very stable release is cut and all new code is
>   integrated into the develop branch. You regularly push both of these
>   branches to the public repository. Each time you have a new topic
>   branch to merge in, you merge it into develop; then, when you tag a
>   release, you fast-forward master to wherever the now-stable develop
>   branch is.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative option @krisz!

Comment: The non-plumbing-command variant sometimes requires a `git rm -r .` step: `git checkout stage -- :/` won't *remove* paths that exist in the index but not in the commit named by `stage`.

Comment: Indeed, I better just switch to the new checkout interface.